# How to execute custom code after successful authorization?

Tags: identityserver4

Client app is redirecting to IdentityServer4 instance - "/connect/authorize/callback"?client_id=...".
If the user is not logged in(has no cookie) he is redirected to the Login page and on postback I can execute random logic(subscribe the user to this client - add claim to the user's claims collection with the client_id).

If the user has valid cookie there is no login screen and IdentityServer4 redirects him back to the Client app with the requested tokens in the query string (the consent is turned off).

How can I execute custom code when this event occurs?

Answer (score 4):

A "login success" event is available from the [Built-In Events](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/events.html#built-in-events). Unfortunately, Identity Server events are logging-oriented, so you must implement [`IEventSink`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/events.html#custom-sinks) to capture events, and you probably can't do things like show UI without interrupting the rest of the OIDC flow. This also means you can't log events unless you manually handle it in your `IEventSink` implementation (see the [`DefaultEventSink`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Services/DefaultEventSink.cs), it just serializes the event to whatever logger is registered for injection). The event is raised by the [`TokenRequestValidator`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/c7eade457ec75a6ea99af307293776011a8d1717/src/IdentityServer4/Validation/TokenRequestValidator.cs#L730).

First, enable "success" events in the configuration...

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
});
```

...then look for the `UserLoginSuccessEvent`.

```cs
public class LoginEventSink : IEventSink
{
    public Task PersistAsync(Event evt)
    {
        if(evt.Id.Equals(EventIds.UserLoginSuccess))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

One of the [overloads](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Events/UserLoginSuccessEvent.cs#L39) tells you whether the login was interactive by setting `Event.Endpoint` to `UI` but I don't see a way to get that from `IEventSink`, not really sure how it's used. You might be able to check the OIDC "Prompt" mode for `None` if you need that.

Depending on your setup and requirements, you could also capture an event on the client side when the challenge returns, but it sounds like you want to keep this in Identity Server.

Comment: Since it is a Task, you should return (add at the end line of method) : return Task.CompletedTask;

Comment: Does this worked for anyone? For me this piece of code is not executing.